# Create subtotal that adds up points as radio buttons are clicked in succession - not all at once

Tags: javascript

I have created a form with radio buttons with points. I would like to know how to subtotal the points as they earn them - a running total. Only one radio button will be selected at a time. I'm a rank beginner at coding but avid. Thank you.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option? (Makes for a very simple amount of code...)

Comment: You should provide some more information, especially some example code, results you expect and what you have tried so far.

Comment: //Here is the form with the radio buttons. I want to use these to add up points as my students do the activities (online). It needs to be a running sub-total so they can see their points accumulate.

Comment: //Here is the link to the form with the radio buttons. I want to use these to add up points as my students do the activities (online). It needs to be a running sub-total so they can see their points accumulate. http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~wellhous/project/activities/ecology_lessons/points.htm

Comment: I've tried about 10 different pieces of code but the only thing that would happen is that it would put in one amount, like a sub-total before adding tax to buy something. I have not found anything that will continue to add points for a running total.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery but am willing to learn and willing to use whatever works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started. Presumably you have multiple choice questions and you want to update the total based on whether the correct answer has been chosen or not.

A very simple implementation is to put a single click listener on the form and run the sub-total each time based on selected radio buttons:

```
<form action="" onclick="updateTotal(this);">
  <table style="border: 1px solid #666666;">
    <tr>
      <td>Question 1
      <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">wrong answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">wrong answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">right answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">wrong answer<br>
    <tr>
      <td>Question 2
      <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">wrong answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">wrong answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">wrong answer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">right answer<br>
    <tr>
      <td>Your total:
      <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" value="0">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Clear form">
      <td><input type="submit" value="Send answers">
  </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateTotal(form) {
    var el, els = form.elements;
    var subtotal = 0;

    for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      el = els[i];
      if (el.type == 'radio') subtotal += el.checked? Number(el.value) : 0;
    }
    form.subtotal.value = subtotal; 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try. It is like multiple choice questions. When they complete an activity a question, appears that is easily answered if they just did the activity - no penalty, i.e. wrong answer. By answering the question they get the points. It is a scenario, and there are also some questions included that have 3 choices. There is not a wrong answer, which ever answer they choose leads them to what they need to know next - another activity. More of a level of mastery type lesson.

Comment: It works beautifully now. Thank you so much for the help. Here is the link to the final product in case someone else can use it:http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~wellhous/project/activities/ecology_lessons/points.htm

Comment: I'd like to give you credit for this on the website when the lesson is finished. Should I just link to Stack Overflow? or should I link to Rob G.? or both? Thanks very much.